# unable to install ubuntu-sdk

Tags: ubuntu-sdk, qt-creator

```
qtcreator-plugin-ubuntu: Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1) but 1:4.9-20140406-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
                         Depends: libqt5core5a (>= 5.2.0) but 5.2.1+dfsg-1ubuntu14.2 is to be installed
                         Depends: libqt5gui5-gles (>= 5.0.2) but it is not going to be installed
                         Depends: libqt5qml5 (>= 5.0.2) but 5.2.1-3ubuntu15.1 is to be installed
                         Depends: libqt5quick5-gles (>= 5.0.2) but it is not going to be installed
                         Depends: libqt5script5 (>= 5.0.2) but 5.2.1+dfsg-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
                         Depends: libqt5scripttools5 (>= 5.0.2) but 5.2.1+dfsg-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
                         Depends: libqt5widgets5 (>= 5.2.0) but 5.2.1+dfsg-1ubuntu14.2 is to be installed
                         Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 4.1.1) but 4.8.2-19ubuntu1 is to be installed
                         Depends: libudev1 (>= 183) but 204-5ubuntu20.3 is to be installed
```

Comment: Can you add the rest of the output of the apt-get command?  Which OS are you using?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I resolve unmet dependencies?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies)

Answer (score 0):

Did you install the qt sdk, you have a lot libqt unmet dependencies

```
sudo apt-get install qt-sdk
```

And try again

Comment: $ sudo apt-get install qt-sdk
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 qt-sdk : Depends: libqt4-opengl-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages

Comment: it is also not installing

Comment: sudo apt-get install libqt4-opengl-dev

Comment: Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libqt4-opengl-dev : Depends: libgl1-mesa-dev but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libglu1-mesa-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: You can run this command- dpkg --get-selections | grep hold -tell me what it says

Comment: same error again no change

Comment: It should just give a list dpkg --get-selections | grep hold

Comment: Do not install it just run what I typed and tell me the response